# How to display the underline at the end of the text?

Tags: html, css

I am displaying underline below the heading at the end which is displaying but in mobile I am getting one issue. I have to display the underline at the end of the heading text. As of now it is displaying at the end.

****Note:** I have to display only 75px width(I'll increase according to requirement) of the underline. Each section have different heading so i have to display on 75px.**

**Desktop**

[image]

**Mobile**

[image]

**This is my expected output**

[image]

```css
.section-title h2 {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.section-title h2::before {
  content: "";
  border-bottom: 4px solid #E43D32;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 75px;
  right: 0;
  bottom: -8px;
}
.section-title h2 span{color:red;}
 
@media all and (max-width: 768px) {
  .section-title h2 {
    font-size: 40px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="section-title">
  <h2><span>OTHER</span> SUPER HEADING</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Why dont you set your last word into a `span` and apply a `border-bottom` to it using `before or after`

Comment: @MaxiGui, I used span for OTHER  because i am targeting the every span in the h2 tad with color. I think  before and after is the good way to use undeline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another idea without changing the HTML where the trick is to use negative margin and you can keep the pseudo element inline (no need position:absolute)

```css
.section-title h2 {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.section-title h2::after {
  content: "";
  border-bottom: 4px solid #E43D32;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 75px;
  margin-left:-75px;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  transform:translateY(2px); /* adjust this to control the position */
}
.section-title h2 span{color:red;}
 
@media all and (max-width: 768px) {
  .section-title h2 {
    font-size: 40px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="section-title">
  <h2><span>OTHER</span> SUPER HEADING</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Give me sometime to check your answer

Comment: Your answer is working on local. Give me some time check on server.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="section-title">
  <h2><span>OTHER</span> SUPER <u>HEADING</u></h2>
</div>
```

Just use underline tag

[image: Output]

```
<div class="section-title">
  <h2><span>OTHER</span> SUPER HEAD<u>ING</u></h2>
</div>

[![Output][2]][2]
```

Comment: No not like that. I am not displaying the full underline. I have to show only half and I belive before and after is a good way to handle this issues.

Comment: means half the word like Heading U need to underline the word "ING" am i right

Comment: No, I have to display  only 75px width of the underline. Each section have different heading so i have to display on 75px.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the text inside in a `span` and apply pseudo classes to that `span`.

```css
.section-title h2 span {
  position: relative;
}

.section-title h2 span::before {
  content: "";
  border-bottom: 4px solid #E43D32;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 75px;
  right: 0;
  bottom: -8px;
}

@media all and (max-width: 768px) {
  .section-title h2 {
font-size: 50px;
  }
}
`
```

```html
<div class="section-title">
  <h2><span>OTHER SUPER HEADING</span></h2>
</div>
```

**Edit:** As you said you want to target all `span` inside `h2` and apply styling to the `span`, you can add `display: inline` to the `h2` (to the original structure of your code).

Like so -

```css
.section-title h2 {
  position: relative;
  display: inline;
}

.section-title h2::before {
  content: "";
  border-bottom: 4px solid #E43D32;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 75px;
  right: 0;
  bottom: -8px;
}
.section-title h2 span { color: red; }
 
@media all and (max-width: 768px) {
  .section-title h2 {
font-size: 50px;
  }
}
`
```

```html
<div class="section-title">
  <h2><span>OTHER</span> SUPER HEADING</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: This is the good idea to do but I have one issue in this. I am targetting each span which is inside h2 and adding the color. Let me update my code

Comment: I added one css in the question  .section-title h2 span{color:red;}

Comment: I tried inline but it's displaying like this in mobile https://prnt.sc/v4drog

Comment: have you removed the `span` styling from css?

Comment: Yes, I removed for time being.

Answer (score -1):

Try this out

```css
.section-title h2 {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.section-title h2 span {
  text-decoration: red underline;
}


@media all and (max-width: 768px) {
  .section-title h2 {
    font-size: 40px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="section-title"> <h2>OTHER SUPER HEAD<span>ING</span></h2> </div>
```

Comment: No, I have to display only 75px width of the underline. Each section have different heading so i have to display on 75px.